# How can I get Beautytips Module to work with Views field output?

Tags: views, 6

I have uploaded the module Beautytips, and enabled it as usual. I have a content type called Solicitation. From among many fields I have the two main fields (Title and Remarks). I listened to a tutorial video, but it seems it takes one too far than my simple needs. I have a view in which I made the Remarks field to be excluded from view and I followed that field with the title and and I set  option ( Output this field as a link) and I filled the the (Alt text:) with [field_remarks_value] . I have a block view. When I hover on the title I get only ordinary tooltip, while in the setup I selected the Transparent style. I guess I am missing something that I must fill like a selector that I must fill somewhere. Can someone with expertise in this help me. I would be much appreciating.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the BeautyTips module but its not the default behaviour as it does not have [Views integration](https://drupal.org/node/444466) built-in. Fortunately, your BeautyTips use case is rather simple so the approach [outlined here](http://www.wootenswebdesign.com/quick-and-easy-beauty-tips) will work for you. Specifically, you want to edit your 'Title' field to rewrite it to add a custom trigger class like this:

```
<span class='btytp' title='[markup]'>[title]</span>
```

and then add this to the header of the view:

```
<?php
drupal_add_js (
  '$(document).ready(function()
  {
    $(".btytp").bt();
  }); ',
    'inline');
?>
```

However, by doing this you're effectively bypassing the BeautyTips module altogether and won't be using the built-in styles the module provides. Fortunately, this is easy to fix. If you look in the modules file, you'll see all of the styles defined as Arrays that are then converted into a javascript array and used to instantiate the beautytips instance. So for example, if I were using the Hulu style, I would find this array:

```
  $styles['hulu'] = array(
    'fill' => '#F4F4F4',
    'strokeStyle' => '#666666',
    'spikeLength' => 20,
    'spikeGirth' => 10,
    'width' => 350,
    'overlap' => 0,
    'centerPointY' => 1,
    'cornerRadius' => 0,
    'cssStyles' => array(
      'fontFamily' => '"Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif',
      'fontSize' => '12px',
      'padding' => '10px 14px'
    ),
    'shadow' => TRUE,
    'shadowColor' => 'rgba(0,0,0,.5)',
    'shadowBlur' => 8,
    'shadowOffsetX' => 4,
    'shadowOffsetY' => 4,
  );
```

All of the values here are what you need to pass to javascript when you invoke it on your own. So, to do this using the code we already have with the Hulu style, that would look like:

```
<?php
drupal_add_js (
  '$(document).ready(function()
  {
    $(".btytp").bt({
        fill: '#F4F4F4',
        strokeStyle: '#666',
        spikeLength: '20',
        spikeGirth: '10',
        width: 350,
        cornerRadius: 0,
        cornerPointY: 1,
        strokeWidth: 0,
        cssStyles: {
                fontFamily: '"Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif',
                fontSize: '12px',
                padding: '10px 14px'
        },
        shadow: true,
        shadowColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.5)',
        shadowBlur: 8,
        shadowOffsetX: 4,
        shadowOffsetY: 4,
        shadowBlur: 8,
    });
  }); ',
    'inline');
?>
```

Comment: Bunch of thanks, this has worked like magic. I am so grateful.

Comment: I note that despite changing the style of the tooltip, hovering produces the same default style and refuses to change.

Comment: Right - thats a longer answer, i've updated this above. I've run into this exact same instance before and used this method successfully and then disabled / removed the beautytips module and added the library on my own to save a little overhead.

Comment: I think you answered my question before I asked it. Tons of thanks and may be more you deserve. I will study the code and try it.

Comment: I checked the module and you were right that I could find the $styles['hulu'] = array( set to the Netflix style, which is apparently is bypassed. When I replaced the short php code you provided with the longer one, I received a journal of errors which I provided some of them here

An error occurred at /bbc/admin/build/views/ajax/preview/inma.

Error Description: { &quot;display&quot;: &quot;\x3cdiv class=\&quot;views-messages\&quot;\x3e\x3cdiv class=\&quot;messages warning\&quot;\x3e\nThe string \x3cem

Why do you think this is happening? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but where to convert it from ? I only changed the input format to PHP.

Comment: You need to reformat the arrays from PHP into Javascript following the examples above, its just a formatting issue. However, we're getting off-topic here and out of scope for the site. I can help you with your jquery issue if you post it to jsfiddle.net but if this has resolved your issue with getting beautytips integrated with views, please accept the answer and we can open up new threads if necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking me thus far with this topic. As I am still not comfortable with converting arrays from PHP into Javascript, I am here accepting the answer and hoping a new thread in this would be opened up.

Comment: Sarmad - post your array to the site jsfiddle.net and add the link back here.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sarmad54/xEPSs/1/