# How to convert the php array format to javascript array format

Tags: views

I uploaded the Beautytips module and I was able with some help from a member of this site to integrate some code into views, but I could not convert the PHP array format into JavaScript format. The code that I stopped at is the following.

```
drupal_add_js (
  '$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btytp").bt(
        fill: '#F4F4F4',
        strokeStyle: '#666',
        spikeLength: '20',
        spikeGirth: '10',
        width: 350,
        cornerRadius: 0,
        cornerPointY: 1,
        strokeWidth: 0,
        cssStyles: {
          fontFamily: '"Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif',
          fontSize: '12px',
          padding: '10px 14px'
        },
        shadow: true,
        shadowColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.5)',
        shadowBlur: 8,
        shadowOffsetX: 4,
        shadowOffsetY: 4,
        shadowBlur: 8,
    );
  });', 'inline');
```

This code should be used in the Basic Settings of a view block. 
I would be very grateful for any help in this regard, as I am not comfortable with JavaScript.

Comment: tried drupal_json_encode ?

Comment: This is a continuation question from this thread http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/82098/how-can-i-get-beautytips-module-to-work-with-views-field-output/82105

Comment: I recently read about drupal_jason_encode but I don't know how to get it work for me in the above code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the jquery mostly right, you're just missing the brackets that would indicate that its an array for the list of options that follow. Try this jsfiddle here, modified from the one you had sent earlier:

http://jsfiddle.net/xEPSs/10/

Note that for this jsfiddle, I've include the jquery 1.6.2 library and the beautytips library but removed your php code.

You've not got two options to include this in your view. You can add it as a separate javascript file through your theme to have it included on every page, or you can continue to add it in to the header of just that one view with this code:

```
drupal_add_js ('
$(document).ready(function() {
          $(".btytp").bt({
                fill: '#F4F4F4',
                strokeStyle: '#666',
                spikeLength: '20',
                spikeGirth: '10',
                width: 350,
                cornerRadius: 0,
                cornerPointY: 1,
                strokeWidth: 0,
                cssStyles: {
                    fontFamily: '"Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif',
                    fontSize: '12px',
                    padding: '10px 14px'
                },
                shadow: true,
                shadowColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.5)',
                shadowBlur: 8,
                shadowOffsetX: 4,
                shadowOffsetY: 4,
                shadowBlur: 8,
        });
    });', 'inline');
```

Comment: The above code is still not working on the view while the one on the JSFiddle works but only on the Preview of the view. After saving the view with the JSFiddle version the tooltip reverts to the regular view i.e loses formatting, and it worked only for the preview. The JSFiddle version worked for the Preview only after wrapping the code with <script></script> and the input fortmat set to (FULL HTML). Is there anything that could be missing for the above code and the JSFiddle version which worked partially i.e on Preview only? Thanks

Comment: Do you have the beautytips library set to load on every page? If so, then you have three options here: fix the php code to get this to work in the view header as designed above, add it inline in the view header by wrapping it in script tags, or add it as a separate javascript file with script tags in your theme.

Comment: It worked like a treat. I had already set the library to work on every page but I did not notice that the (class=btytp) on (Rewrite the output of this field) had to be replaced with beautytips class. Once I did the replacement, it worked like magic. You great man I wish would repay you  with a similar favor one day. One last question: If I want to add it as a separate javascript file in my theme, can you give me some brief instructions. I am confused how this would override the default tooltip behavior. Many thanks.

Comment: Number of ways to do this, all outlined here in the handbook: https://drupal.org/node/304255. Please remember to actually accept (click checkmark) and upvote answers if they have resolved your issue as this will give you more reputation and encourage other users to respond more quickly to your questions.